# mvvm how to make a list view auto scroll to a new Item in a list view

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, scroll

I am using the MVVM pattern, I have a view which creates a new `ViewModel`, after the user clicks save, this view is closed and a seperate view is opened which displays a collection of view models in a `ListView`.

This `ListView` is sorted in alphabetical order, so the new `ViewModel` may appear at the bottom of the `ListBox`, which is not immediately visible to the user.

My question is how do I get the view to auto scroll to the newly added item?

I guess that It will be using attached behaviours, and the `ScrollIntoView` event on the `ListView`, however its which event that I need to capture from the `GridView` that I am unsure of..

Cheers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This solution is for a ListBox, but it could be modified for a ListView...  This will scroll the selected item into view when you change the selected item from the ViewModel.

Class:

```
/// <summary>
/// ListBoxItem Behavior class
/// </summary>
public static class ListBoxItemBehavior
{
    #region IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBoxItem"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool GetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(ListBoxItem listBoxItem)
    {
        return (bool)listBoxItem.GetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected value
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBoxItem"></param>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    public static void SetIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected(
      ListBoxItem listBoxItem, bool value)
    {
        listBoxItem.SetValue(IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Determins if the ListBoxItem is bought into view when enabled
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(ListBoxItemBehavior),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Action to take when item is brought into view
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="depObj"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    static void OnIsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelectedChanged(
      DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem item = depObj as ListBoxItem;
        if (item == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            return;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            item.Selected += OnListBoxItemSelected;
        else
            item.Selected -= OnListBoxItemSelected;
    }

    static void OnListBoxItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Only react to the Selected event raised by the ListBoxItem 
        // whose IsSelected property was modified.  Ignore all ancestors 
        // who are merely reporting that a descendant's Selected fired. 
        if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(sender, e.OriginalSource))
            return;

        ListBoxItem item = e.OriginalSource as ListBoxItem;
        if (item != null)
            item.BringIntoView();
    }

    #endregion // IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected
}
```

Add the xmlns to your view:

```
xmlns:util="clr-namespace:YourNamespaceHere.Classes"
```

Add the style to the resources of the Window/UserControl:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
        <Setter Property="util:ListBoxItemBehavior.IsBroughtIntoViewWhenSelected" Value="true"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Implement the listbox:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}"
         DisplayMemberPath="Title"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" 
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContainerStyle}"/>
```

Comment: Brent thanks for this, its exactly what I am looking for, thanks!  The only thing is that I have disabled the SelectedItem on my Listview, this is because I have a "edit" link on each row, Is there another event that I could bind this dependency property to?
Thanks

Comment: I modified your class to work with a ListView, and it does not seem to work for me.  My ListView's SelectionMode is Multiple, and my ScrollViewer's CanContentScroll Property is true and its VerticalScrollBarVisibility is Auto.  Additionally, the IsSelected Property of the ListViewItem is bound <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected}"/>.  When the user manually selects an item, the OnListViewItemSelected function fires and the screen scrolls.  However, when I programmatically change my VM item's Selected property, the function OnListViewItemSelected is never fired.

Comment: I should also note that the ListView is not visible when item is programmatically selected.  I suspect that would interfere with the scolling, but not the firing of the OnListViewItemChanged function.

Comment: Unable to get this working. Items not directly in the view, won't respond to selection.

Answer (score 3):

Add a selected item DependecyProperty to the class which contains the collection. Bind the SelectedItem of the listview to it. After adding the new model to the collection set the selected item DependencyProperty.

Comment: Hi Sascha, Thanks for your reply, this makes sense, the only this is that I have turned off the focusable property on the Listview, this is because I only want the Item to be Highlighted one they click a "Edit hyperlink" on the gridview, is it possible to make the selected list item hightlight transparent?

Comment: You can make the selected listitem transparent by creating a style or template for the item.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using `ListBox`.  To implement auto-scrolling, you can create a custom control!

---

#### C#

```
public class LoggingListBox : ListBox
{
    ///<summary>
    ///Define the AutoScroll property. If enabled, causes the ListBox to scroll to 
    ///the last item whenever a new item is added.
    ///</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AutoScroll", 
            typeof(Boolean), 
            typeof(LoggingListBox), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                true, //Default value.
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange | 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                AutoScroll_PropertyChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets whether or not the list should scroll to the last item 
    /// when a new item is added.
    /// </summary>
    [Category("Common")] //Indicate where the property is located in VS designer.
    public bool AutoScroll
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AutoScrollProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AutoScrollProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the AutoScroll property is changed.
    /// This delegates the call to SubscribeToAutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged().
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="d">The DependencyObject whose property was changed.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Change event args.</param>
    private static void AutoScroll_PropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SubscribeToAutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged(
            (LoggingListBox)d,
            (bool)e.NewValue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Subscribes to the list items' collection changed event if AutoScroll is enabled.
    /// Otherwise, it unsubscribes from that event.
    /// For this to work, the underlying list must implement INotifyCollectionChanged.
    ///
    /// (This function was only creative for brevity)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listBox">The list box containing the items collection.</param>
    /// <param name="subscribe">Subscribe to the collection changed event?</param>
    private static void SubscribeToAutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged(
        LoggingListBox listBox, bool subscribe)
    {
        INotifyCollectionChanged notifyCollection =
            listBox.Items.SourceCollection as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (notifyCollection != null)
        {
            if (subscribe)
            {
                //AutoScroll is turned on, subscribe to collection changed events.
                notifyCollection.CollectionChanged += 
                    listBox.AutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged;
            }
            else
            {
                //AutoScroll is turned off, unsubscribe from collection changed events.
                notifyCollection.CollectionChanged -= 
                    listBox.AutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler called only when the ItemCollection changes
    /// and if AutoScroll is enabled.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The ItemCollection.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Change event args.</param>
    private void AutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged(
        object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            int count = Items.Count;
            ScrollIntoView(Items[count - 1]);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor a new LoggingListBox.
    /// </summary>
    public LoggingListBox()
    {
        //Subscribe to the AutoScroll property's items collection 
        //changed handler by default if AutoScroll is enabled by default.
        SubscribeToAutoScroll_ItemsCollectionChanged(
            this, (bool)AutoScrollProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue);
    }
}
```

#### XAML

Here is how you use the control in XAML:

```
<tools:LoggingListBox/> <!-- AutoScroll="true" by default. -->
```

Somewhere you need to specify how you access this control.  This completely depends on your project setup.

```
xmlns:tools="clr-namespace:MyCustomControls;assembly=MyCustomControls"
```

#### How it Works

To create a custom control you should only need C# code.  We do this by extending a `ListBox` and only add a single property, *AutoScroll*.  Because it is a dependency property, it will partake in the WPF binding system, which also makes it available in the Visual Studio designer.

*Covering dependency properties is a rather large topic, but is integral to create custom controls.  You can learn more on the [Control Authoring Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745025(v=vs.100).aspx) or the [Dependency Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752914(v=vs.100).aspx).*

The objective is to subscribe to the collection changed event of the underlying item collection so we can respond by scrolling to the bottom whenever a new item is added.  We must subscribe to this event at two places.

1. Whenever `AutoScroll` is set to *true*, we need to subscribe.  The value of `AutoScroll` may change at any time and we should be able to respond accordingly.  If set to *false*, we should instruct the control to stop scrolling to the bottom by unsubscribing.
2. Supposing `AutoScroll` needs to only be set at compile-time, we need a method of subscribing upon startup.  This is done by using the control's constructor.

#### Why Create a Custom Control

First and foremost, we have simplified the XAML as far as reasonably possible.  We only need to access the control and optionally specify or bind to the `AutoScroll` property.

It is MVVM compliant.  Our view-model doesn't need to worry about the `AutoScroll` functionality because it is self-contained in the control.  At the same time, the view model can provide a property which the `AutoScroll` property is bound to, giving us the desired decoupling of the view & view-model.

Additionally, we have avoided the use of behaviors.  This means we have removed two dependencies from our project (granted this was the only reason those dependencies were included in the first place).  We can safely omit *System.Windows.Interactivity* and *Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions* from the project references.

#### Drawbacks

There is only one drawback to this approach.  The underlying items collection must implement `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  In most cases, this is a non-issue.  If you are using MVVM, you probably already have your items wrapped up inside an `ObservableCollection`, which already implements our required interface.

Enjoy! :-)

Answer (score -2):

This might not apply for WPF, but in WinForms the code is similar to `lstData.EnsureVisible(itemIndex);`

Answer (score -2):

hmm talk about overkill, for a more simple approach and the one i imagine most will use....

for listview simply whack in:

```
listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.Items.Count - 1);
```

And for Listbox simply whack in:

```
listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1; 
listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

To your listview item add (..etc) method...
.. or whack it on a timer tick.

The above way under OP seems to much to do for me i am lazy...
All code explains its self.

Comment: mmm... perhaps, but the question was asked how to do this using the MVVM design pattern.  For those who don't use the design pattern this approach would probably work.

Comment: For the WPF version of ListView, the EnsureVisible method does not exist.