# Is there a simple way to have a ListView automatically scroll to the most recently added item without having to write any code in the code behind?

Tags: wpf, listview, scroll

I have a ListView which is bound to an observable collection. As items are added to the observable collection, the listview does not automatically scroll to show the most recently added item.  I am trying to adhere to good WPF practices and would like to avoid writing any code in the view's code-behind.  Is there a simple way to accomplish this through the XAML or the corresponding Model's code?

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding ScenarioSnippets}" Background="{x:Null}" 
                      BorderBrush="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" SelectionMode="Single" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView Selector.IsSelected="True" AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ScenarioSnippetItemCellTemplate}" 
                                            HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource GridViewHeaderStyle}" />
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: I know only solution using `ListView.ScrollIntoView()` it would be interesting to see XAML only solution

Answer (score 9):

You could use a Blend behavior:

```
public class AutoScrollToLastItemBehavior : Behavior<ListBox>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        var collection = AssociatedObject.Items.SourceCollection as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection != null)
            collection.CollectionChanged += collection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        var collection = AssociatedObject.Items.SourceCollection as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        if (collection != null)
            collection.CollectionChanged -= collection_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void collection_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            ScrollToLastItem();
        }
    }

    private void ScrollToLastItem()
    {
        int count = AssociatedObject.Items.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            var last = AssociatedObject.Items[count - 1];
            AssociatedObject.ScrollIntoView(last);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="...">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:AutoScrollToLastItemBehavior />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</ListView>
```

(the `Behavior` and `Interaction` classes can be found in `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` in the Blend SDK)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an [Attached Behavior](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachedBehaviors.aspx) which will allow your `ListView` to honor the MVVM paradigm which is what you are ultimately after.

A solution/example with `ListBox` (easily modified for a `ListView`) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317194/mvvm-how-to-make-a-list-view-auto-scroll-to-a-new-item-in-a-list-view).