# WPF control to show snippet of a list that auto-scrolls to center on an item

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my model I have a near-infinite list of items. Let's assume the items are -9999, ..., 0,+1,+2,+3, ...., +9999, with items having an increment of 1 between them.

I would like to display a list of 5 of the items, centered on an "item of interest". The "item of interest" changes by 1 at a time, either up or down, at any time. When it changes I would like the control to do an animated pixel by pixel "scroll" until it centers on the new item of interest. The user can not scroll, so the list is always centered on the "item of interest"

Assume the item of interest is 3, then the displayed list should look as follows:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Now the item of interest changes to 4, so after the scroll animation the displayed list should look as follows:

```
2
3
4
5
6
```

I'm using c# and WPF. Are there existing controls out there that do this, open source or commercial?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each item is located in a Control, you can call the [BringIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.bringintoview.aspx) method, that will make the containing ScrollViewer scroll to the desired item.

Here is a similar question, using the MVVM pattern : [mvvm how to make a list view auto scroll to a new Item in a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317194/mvvm-how-to-make-a-list-view-auto-scroll-to-a-new-item-in-a-list-view)

Comment: I assumed the 'BringIntoView' method would not do a pixel-by-pixel scroll animation, but simply change the displayed area instantly. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct, forgot about the animation.