# Use tree view to control list view scrolling behavior

Tags: wpf, listview, behavior

I have a tree view that displays a structure of agenda items. The tree structure is merely for ui and usability purposes. The tree view is “flattened” into a linear list of agenda items. When an item is selected in the tree view, I would like to scroll the corresponding linear list item to the top of the listview.
The items in the listview are custom user controls.
I would like to use an attached behavior since I need to stay within MVVM. I have manly to issues. I need to be able to inject an index into the view and trigger the scroll itself by a command. 
Any ideas?
Kind regards

This approach seem feasible but Im not getting how to pass an index to a behavior. https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/09/30/scrolltobottom-behavior-for-listview-in-mvvm-based-universal-windows-apps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This StackOverflow question should help you:
[mvvm how to make a list view auto scroll to a new item in a list view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317194/mvvm-how-to-make-a-list-view-auto-scroll-to-a-new-item-in-a-list-view)

You shouldn't need to deal with an `Index` if you're using MVVM, just use the selected item instead. Ideally, your TreeView and ListView should be binding to the same items.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped a lot. I will mark this as answerd.